# Psci Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined when using port

Tags: purescript

I'm running psci with port for example

```
pulp psci -- -p9000
```

and it borks with

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at PSCI.Data.BigInt (bundle.js:52952)
    at bundle.js:53042
```

Found this require here

```
.psci_modules/node_modules/Data.BigInt/foreign.js
```

I could not find some docs explaining this, am I doing this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `Data.BigInt` depends on the `big-integer` NPM package, which is not available in the browser when running with `--port`.

To make this work, you would need some way to provide a dummy `require` function in the browser.

Comment: How to supply additional scripts to psci-started web server?

Comment: There isn't a standard way. Perhaps you could get it to work using an FFI module, but the proper approach would be to support it properly in PSCi.